# How to set attack speed

Tags: 3d, animation, rpg, combat, godot-3

I was checking the new animation with that Mixamo right I made for combo attacks at various speeds.... and I realized I never thought about how implement it in-game.

[image: Animation screenshot]

Is there a simple, fast and straight forward method to just tell Godot "hey if this player has more attack speed %, then speed up this animation by that same %"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can set the `custom_speed` argument when calling `play`.**

For example, to play an animation at half speed you do this:

```
$AnimationPlayer.play("animation_name", -1, 0.5)
```

Here `custom_speed` is `0.5` (i.e half speed).

*The `-1` is telling the `AnimationPlayer` to use the default blending between animations (these are blending times set in the transitions between animations, by default there is no blending, but you can configure them in the "Edit Transitions" option of the "Animation" menu in he "Animation" panel).*

---

Or if you need more fine control, you can set the `playback_process_mode` to "Manual" so you can use `seek` and `advance` to advance the animation.

---

Be aware that `AnimationPlayer` in Godot 4 has a `speed_scale` property, and in Godot 3 it has a `playback_speed`, which you can use to make all the animations play faster or slower.

So if you cannot use the `play` method, you may react to the `animation_started` signal and set the `speed_scale`/`playback_speed`.

---

I have a couple extra tricks for you:

- You can add a "Call Method Track" to your animation, and use it to set the `speed_scale`/`playback_speed` at the start of the animation. *This won't work for animations from an imported scene (e.g. a gltf model), as you cannot modify those, so...*
- You can make an `AnimationPlayer` that plays animations from another `AnimationPlayer` using an "Animation Playback Track". So you can have another `AnimationPlayer` work as a proxy for the `AnimationPlayer` from the imported scene. Sadly this track does not let you set the speed either, but you might combine it with setting `speed_scale`/`playback_speed` from a "Call Method Track". *With this you won't be able play multiple animations of the same animation player at the same time (for that you need an `AnimationTree`), but it might play multiple animations of multiple different `AnimationPlayer`s in sync.*

---

Sadly there is no way to control the playback speed from an `AnimationTree`. Also be aware that an `AnimationTree` could play multiple animations at the same time, so setting `speed_scale`/`playback_speed` might NOT work as desired.